# Service Broker -- how to extract the rows from the XML message?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Say I have the following situation (for demonstration). The simple table content is converted to an XML value and sent via Service Broker to another SQL server where the result of the `SELECT` is to be stored in the non-XML form (i.e. usual, simple database table). Let's try:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (a int, b int, c int);
GO

INSERT INTO tab (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 11, 111);
INSERT INTO tab (a, b, c) VALUES (2, 22, 222);
INSERT INTO tab (a, b, c) VALUES (3, 33, 333);
INSERT INTO tab (a, b, c) VALUES (4, 44, 444);
GO

SELECT * FROM tab FOR XML RAW, TYPE;
GO
```

When capturing the value to the message, it looks like:

```
<row a="1" b="11" c="111" />
<row a="2" b="22" c="222" />
<row a="3" b="33" c="333" />
<row a="4" b="44" c="444" />
```

i.e. single multiline string. Say, I create the exactly same table structure at the destination machine:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_destination (a int, b int, c int);
```

What is the best way to extract the rows from the `@msg`, and how to put them to the destination table?

Thanks, Petr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tab (a int, b int, c int); 
GO 

INSERT INTO tab (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 11, 111); 
INSERT INTO tab (a, b, c) VALUES (2, 22, 222); 
INSERT INTO tab (a, b, c) VALUES (3, 33, 333); 
INSERT INTO tab (a, b, c) VALUES (4, 44, 444); 
GO 

CREATE TABLE tab_destination (a int, b int, c int); 
go

declare @x xml = (SELECT * FROM tab FOR XML RAW, TYPE); 

insert into tab_destination (a, b, c)
select 
    x.value('@a', 'int'),
    x.value('@c', 'int'),
    x.value('@b', 'int')
    from @x.nodes('//row') t(x);
GO 

select * from tab_destination;
go
```

Time to read [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Remus and @Janis: I am reading the recommended doc, but I do not understand one related detail. Please, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578904/sql-server-how-to-shred-one-multielement-xml-to-single-element-xml-values-ins

Answer (score 1):

And other option (i would prefer Remus Rusanu example though.. If a lots of columns and table structures are the same, this helps get lazy):

```
declare @x xml = (SELECT * FROM tab FOR XML RAW, root('tab'), TYPE); 

Declare @docHandle int  
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @x

Select *
FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, 'tab//', 1) 
With dbo.Tab

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle
```